# Can't connect to outlet if class is loaded programmatically

Tags: swift, inheritance, tableview, iboutlet, outlet

I have the following problem:
There is a view with the class UniObjectsTableViewController in the storyboard and AreasTableViewController inherits from this class.
Then I load the class AreasTableViewController from code in the following way:

```
let areaViewController = AreasTableViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(areaViewController, animated: true)
```

UniObjectsTableViewController has an outlet to a SDStateTableView.

```
@IBOutlet var stateTableView: SDStateTableView!
```

If I try to print the outlet in the viewDidLoad() method of the AreasTableViewController it's nil.

```
print(stateTableView) => nil
```

Is there any way to acces the outlets of a motherclass in the inherited 
class?

Comment: If you have a class B which inherits from class A containing a connected IBOutlet through storyboard (just open both files side by side and ctrl+drag), then you should present class B loaded from storyboard, that is :

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
let areaViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idThatYouSetup inYourStoryboardForBController");

Comment: But there is no view in the storyboard with class B. The View of Class B is identical to the view from class A.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Step 1: Give your child class instance a name on stoayboard]
Step 1: Give your child class instance a name on stoayboard

[image: Step 2: Open the base class under Manual in the Assistant editor, then you can command+drag]
Step 2: Open the base class under Manual in the Assistant editor, then you can command+drag

Step 3:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let areaViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewController")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(areaViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but if have multiple child classes with the same view. How can I handle that case without copying the view in the storyboard multiple times?